# Find api.nanigans.com error

Tags: jquery

I have an ajax call that repond me in a var a string, that is html code.
`var data = '<html>';`

So to use the power of Jquery, and find some things inside i do

```
var myobject = $(data);
myobject.find('span.something');
```

and it's working fine, BUT i have this error that i do not understand:

> GET
>   chrome-extension://api.nanigans.com/event.php?app_id=9543&type=visit&name=dau&user_id=31477895198
>   jQuery.js:6325
>
> jQuery.extend.clean          jQuery.js:6325
>
> jQuery.buildFragment         jQuery.js:6164
>
> jQuery.extend.parseHTML      jQuery.js:499
>
> jQuery.fn.jQuery.init        jQuery.js:131
>
> jQuery                       jQuery.js:44
>
> $.ajax.success               myfile.js:26
>
> fire                         jQuery.js:974
>
> self.fireWith                jQuery.js:1084
>
> done                         jQuery.js:7803
>
> callback                     jQuery.js:8518

Someone as an idea why? (i think i know that is because i do $(data) but no idea why it's wrong )

Thank you
i apologies if there is already something like that but i found nothing in the search

EDIT :
It's javascript used in an chrome extension, i do not know if it's impact something...

EDIT 2 :
So finaly i found it, when there is an ajax call inside what you get from your own call, the one iside will failed (logical)

Comment: What is the error? all you've shown us is a stacktrace.

Comment: My chrome just say to me : GET chrome-extension://api.nanigans.com/event.php?app_id=9543&type=visit&name=dau&user_id=31477895198 jQuery.js:6325, i have nothing more :/